# How to make an android app for a website by giving the url of that website

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, react-native

Please [Please click on this](http://www.appypie.com/android-app-builder)

I just want to know.. what the algorithm behind the making online apps by
  giving the url of website.

Is there any separate tools for making android app.
  So then friends please help, or any idea to make online app, then please

share..
  Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to make app of a webstie url then it so easy just use webView and use your url in webView. Plus make sure your website has support of mobile phones. For reference see this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use `WebView` in a general case. Otherwise there are some Library for connectivity and getting data from websites and loading in customized view.